# Мониторинг сети

Tags: linux, администрирование, devops

Есть задача наблюдать за 250 айпишниками каким-то ПО, методом ping.

Если ping пропадет на одной машине и даже например через 5 -10 секунд появится, ПО должно сигнализировать об этом, что вот мол был обрыв.Чем можно осуществить такой мониторинг?

Comment: Запрос `софт для мониторинга сети ping` уже пробовали? Неужели ничего не нашлось?

Comment: попробуйте утилиту fping

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix умеет пинговать и умеет слать сообщения при любом событии.

Comment: Zabbix это хорошо, особенно для тех кто его юзал. Хотелось бы просто какую то простую утилиту.

Comment: можно попробовать TheDude